# Pagination avoid duplicate record using primary key

Tags: mysql, sql, pagination

I currently have to paginate records in the database but it's getting duplicates a lot because I need to order by `updated_at` (it's updated when updating record data). For example, a query like this: will return duplicate records if the column `updated_at` being updated usually:

```
select * from news where ... order by updated_at desc LIMIT 10 OFFSET ...
```

So to avoid duplicate I add `id` condition in the query:

```
select * from news where id not in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10) and ... order by updated_at desc LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

In this way, the client has to send `id` to the server to sort out records retrieved. It's work pretty good but I don't find this solution on the internet yet so maybe it has some disadvantage. **My question: is my solution too bad to deploy ?**

Comment: Sample data would help here.  It is not clear to me what your pagination is supposed to be doing.

Comment: You can do this, or you can just let people see duplicates (this should not be surprising to users if records are getting updated by the thing they are sorting them on), or you can read the full set of data, without a limit, and store it somewhere else accessible to the client for paging through (ignoring any updates that happen while they are paging through)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen my pagination is not focused on data, it's focused on unique pagination data so data can be anything

Comment: @ysth beside see duplicates it's maybe missing newly updated record because the new record is always on page 1 (offset 0)